# Creating time series from gridded meteorological dataset in NETCDF4 format

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am creating a time series from a gridded dataset in the NETCDF4 format using the instructions provided in this link: http://www.matteodefelice.name/post/aggregating-gridded-data/

However, at the very end, I get an error when trying to group the temperatures by time, using the code:

x = out_sel.groupby('time').mean()

The following error appears:
"ValueError: cannot reduce over dimensions ['time']. expected either '...' to reduce over all dimensions or one or more of Frozen(SortedKeysDict({'latitude': 5, 'longitude': 8}))."

How can I solve this problem?
Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Matteo De Felice was very kind and answered to my question. The solution is very simple and to efficiently run the code it is necessary to update it as follows:

x = out_sel.groupby('time').mean(...)

I used the code provided by Matteo on the E-OBS dataset focusing on provinces in Italy. Therefore, the code shows to be easily applied to other datasets and purposes.

Comment: To be clear, the solution is literally to put `...` as the argument to `.mean`. The meaning is to take the mean over all dimensions other than `time` so that `time` is the only remaining dimension in the result.